# Unique values - Terms aggregation or Wildcard query

Tags: elasticsearch

What's the best way to get all the unique terms for a field? 
Can use either terms aggregation or a wild card query 
(and then reduce it to unique terms at the application side)?

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : { "text" : "**" }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genres" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "text" }
        }
    }
}
```

Terms aggregation lets elasticsearch reduce the terms to unique values (in a distributed manner) and thereby reduce the response payload. But is it going to put too much load on elasticsearch?

I'm aware of the shard size aspect of the terms aggregation. Other than that, is one internally optimized than the other or not? What's the execution plan for each?

Answer (score 0):

> "An aggregation can be seen as a unit-of-work that builds analytic
>   information over a set of documents"

What you're trying to achieve falls under analytical information, since it is provided out of the box, it is optimized.

use `"explain": true` to get description of score calculation(not useful for aggregations as they do not score documents)

Refer: [Aggregations in ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html)